# how to have more than one object in single vector element?

Tags: c++

Haven't worked with vectors very much, so please excuse my ignorance. I am looking to have a vector of size 10 that can hold multiple instances of a class that I have within the SAME element of the vector. so say for example 
my_vector[3] = my_obj1 and my_obj2

is this even possible? would I need something like a 2d vector to implement this? is there a better solution to my problem? I don't have any code to try so please don't say "where is your code and errors?"

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  What does this solve that having a vector of size 20 (so you're not doubling up on elements) does not?

Comment: @StephenNewell im trying to make a tower defense game and every area of the board can hold more than one instance of the class I created. therefore, how do I store more than one instance in a single element so that I can print every element of my vector to the board?

Comment: "*is there a better solution to my problem?*" But you've never told what your problem is! All you've said is a intended solution! And comment doesn't count. You should edit your question.

Comment: @codyparker, Then the type in your vector has to be something capable of holding more than one of that class.

Comment: @NickyC I don't really have a problem as of yet, im asking a question out of curiosity. in c++ is it possible to have a vector hold more than one instance of a class in a single element of the vector?

Comment: @chris so maybe a vector of vectors?

Comment: You know, we choose the word "element" for a reason: It's *element*. It's by-definition *one single thing*.

Comment: @codyparker, That'll probably work well enough for your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just make a vector of vectors.

```
std::vector<std::vector<MyObj>> vectorOfVectors;
std::vector<MyObj> tempVector;
tempVector.push_back(my_obj1);
tempVector.push_back(my_obj2);
vectorOfVectors.push_back(tempVector);
```

Comment: im getting an error for your last line of code. error states no matching function call

Comment: @Tas thanks for catching that, late night. Very sorry about that, fixed now.